# Does "occurring" mean "happening", "existing" or some other meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, expressions

nature [posts](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/the-order-of-nucleotides-in-a-gene-6525806) this

> In order to understand how Sanger sequencing works, it's first
>   necessary to understand the process of DNA replication as it exists in
>   nature. DNA is a double-stranded, helical molecule composed of
>   nucleotides, each of which contains a phosphate group, a sugar
>   molecule, and a nitrogenous base. Because there are four naturally
>   `occurring` nitrogenous bases, there are four different types of DNA
>   nucleotides: adenine (A), thymine (T), guanine (G), and cytosine (C).

In this context, does "occurring" mean "happening", "existing" or some other meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally occurring means they exist naturally, although it may be possible to create other nitrogenous bases in a laboratory (I'm not a chemist) we would expect to only find the four mentioned nucleotides outside of an artificial environment.